# simple "select" validation in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am stuck with my simple "select" validation by javascript.

Problem is: when validating "select", it does not shows select options to users after validation error

**"select is not enabaling back for user to select options after validation displayed"**

### HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">    

<label for="exampleInputArea">Area</label>
    <select style="color:#000 !important" class="form-control" id="exampleInputArea" placeholder="Select Month" name="exampleInputArea">
        <option value="" >--Select Area--</option>
        <option value="Area1">Area1</option>
        <option value="Area2">Area2</option>
        <option value="Area3">Area3</option>

    </select>
    <div style="color:red;" id="areaerror"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group last">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-red mailbtn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
$('.mailbtn').live('click',function(){

area = $('#exampleInputArea').val();

if(area.lenght==0 || area=='')
        {
            $('#exampleInputArea').html('')
            $('#areaerror').text('Area is Required');
            return false;
        } else { 
            $('#areaerror').text('');
            return true;
        }

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: "mail.php",
        data: {area:area}
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
        $('.mail_middle').html('');
        $('.mail_middle').html('We will call you to confirm your delivery address.<br/>Thank you.');
        return false;
        });
});
```

Here is my js fiddle link:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zPgf/)

Please do help me with solution, as it is wasting my time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to below one,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zPgf/7/)

```
if (area.length == 0 || area == '') {
    $('#exampleInputArea').val('')
    $('#areaerror').text('Area is Required');
    return false;
} else {
    $('#areaerror').text('');
}
```

**YOUR ERROR**

1. it is `length` not `lenght`
2. On error select `val('')` not `html('')`, by `val('')` it will select your value to blank which is your default and by `html('')` it will replace `html` (ie `option`) of your select to blank.
3. On successfull don't return it because you have to perform ajax functionality, by `return true` it will return your function not performing your ajax functionality.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your help, but after selecting value why validation is not hiding? what to do for that?

Comment: it is hiding you have to click submit button, if you want to hide on selection than apply it on on change event of select

Answer (score 1):

your code has some errors :

```
$('.mailbtn').on('click',function(){    
    var area = $('#exampleInputArea').val();
    console.log(area);
    if(area.length==0 || area=='')
            {
                $('#areaerror').text('Area is Required');
                return false;
            } else { 
                $('#areaerror').text('');
                return true;
            }
```

so better use my code and here is the updated fiddle :

**http://jsfiddle.net/aelor/7zPgf/3/**

This will send the ajax only when any area is selected or else it will simply show the validation message

Answer (score 0):

try this *[http://jsfiddle.net/7zPgf/1/][1]*
live was not an good aproach.
try on.

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/7zPgf/1/
```